# Visual Studio my application do not execute (Crash)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crash

I have a problem, I developed an application in visual studio 2012 before with framework 4.0, but then I had to migrate for Framework 4.5 because some things. now the application gets stuck when trying to run on a client computer (that does not have Visual Studio 2012 installed), on the first form appears this:

[image]

and when I click repair, this error appears:

[image]

staff appreciate the maximum help, do not know whether to install a program on the client computer, already I tried to install the PC client framework 4.5.1 did not work and the framework 4.0 also did not work

Comment: This happens because there is an error in your program. It crashes then tries to find a debugger to make you see what happened. But since you're on another computer, no debugger... This is about a Unhandled Exception caught somewhere in your program...

Comment: Is the application in Release mode?

Comment: Mr @HirbodBehnam appear when execute the program on client computer.

Comment: Mr @SuperPeanut   can you give me  a debugger reference? if you see the second image says to enable some debbuger i dont know how ..

Comment: You can try to install visual studio on the client machine... Express version are for free...